# Azure API Management: storing Login event to table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-api-management

**Update**

The link below is used to request token and refresh token depending on a field in the body:

http://example.com/token

**1 Request a token**

A field in the body: grant_type:password

Steps:

1 When the request arrives, APIM forwards it to 3rd party

2 Once APIM receives the reponse from 3rd party, it returns the result to its client.

We want to log data (url, response status code) for this url to Table Storage. Requet for the same url is not logged below:

**2 Refresh the token**
A field in the body: grant_type:refresh_token

Application Insight is used with APIM, I wonder if Table Storage is the best tool.

Is there built-in UI that is available for viewing data stored in Table Storage

Any information or link or code sample would be appreciated.

C#

VS 2017

Comment: Which language you need ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples

Comment: Thx. Please see my update on OP.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to the login event schema you plan to persist ? How are you planning to use (query, update, ie.) the persisted login events ?

Comment: @DoguArslan Good point, please check my udpte.

Answer (score 1):

APIM has a few ways to send data out of request processing pipeline:

- send-request/send-one-way-request allows you to send an HTTP request, you're in charge of constructing request in HTTP terms: method, URL, headers, body.
- log-to-eventhub allows you to send a message to EH. You can specify C# expression that produces message payload.
- AppInsights integration will allow you to record client request, backend request, backend response, and client response for each request processed by APIM. You can configure it to log extra headers and part of body.